# Apache2 not reading my conf file

Tags: apache2

I'm used to apache2 and usually I can get it running without to much of a headache. However this time I stumbled on a problem I can't shake off.

On my local I usually work with nginx but I have this modification to do on a `.htaccess` file. So I installed apache2. Both Apache2 and nginx use port 80 but I disabled nginx for the time being.

I ceated my virtual host file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev-my-site.apache
    ServerAdmin my-email@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-site
</VirtualHost>
```

Basic, but it should be enough, right? There is a symbolic link in the corresponding `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` pointing to this conf file. I restarted apache and added the following entry to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1  dev-my-site.apache
```

From here I expect `http://dev-my-site.apache` to point to `/var/www/html/my-site/` but it doesn't. It points instead to `/var/www/html/` which is my default document root for apache2, and displays the `index.html` file that sits there.

Here is the result of `apache2ctl -S`, which is supposed to list vhosts:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

It seems my virtual host is not taken into account at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you reload Apache after you enabled your vhost (`a2ensite` or creating the symlink in `sites-enabled` manually)? Apache needs to re-read its configuration after it has been changed, for example by adding another vhost. Also, `apache2ctl` doesn't list vhosts, but loaded modules and some central confs. You're probably looking for `apache2ctl -D DUMP_VHOSTS'.

Comment: You're right I put the wrong command here. Thanks for you help, this unblocked me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found the answer I realized this question is [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591889/site-does-not-exist-error-for-a2ensite).

To be short: nginx do not require a specific extension for its configuration files, but apache do.

I forgot to suffix the conf file with the `*.conf` extension, causing the file to not be recognized by apache.

Thanks Henning Kockerbeck, who put me in the right direction.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. It looks like the `.conf` extension has been optional (but highly recommended) for Apache 2.2 and earlier, and is mandatory since Apache 2.4.